# Python ImportError: cannot dynamically load .so executable

Tags: python, importerror, cpython

In python/3.6.5 I receive an `ImportError` with the message: `cannot dynamically load executable`.

Loading and running the python module works without problems on my local machine, but on the remote server I get the `ImportError`. I have double checked that the compilers are at the same level. However for Python I am using 3.7.4 on my local and 3.6.5 on the remote machine.

The problem arises when I try to load the module as:

```
from fastell4py import fastell4py
```

which raises the error:

```
ImportError: .../lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastell4py-0.1.0-py3.6-linux-
x86_64.egg/fastell4py/_fastell.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so:
cannot dynamically load executable
```

Does anyone have an idea about the origin of the error and how to solve it?

The package is available at: https://github.com/sibirrer/fastell4py

Comment: Does the file (*../lib/python3.6/site-packages/fastell4py-0.1.0-py3.6-linux-
x86_64.egg/fastell4py/_fastell.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so*) exist on the remote server?

Comment: Yes, the installation process put it in that location with the following user-persmission: -rwxr-xr-x

Comment: Have you tried using Python version 3.6.5 on your local machine to see if its a version problem?